# How do I get the logs (results) of executing anonymous Apex code in jsforce?

Tags: execute-anonymous, node.js, jsforce, tooling, userinfo

I have been trying to execute the following Apex code in jsforce (Node.js):

```
var apexBody = "System.debug(UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization());";
  conn.tooling.executeAnonymous(apexBody, function(err, res) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log("compiled?: " + res.compiled); // compiled successfully
    console.log("executed?: " + res.success); // executed successfully

    console.log(res, 'res')
    // ...
  });
```

The res object only contains :

```
{ line: -1,
  column: -1,
  compiled: true,
  success: true,
  compileProblem: null,
  exceptionStackTrace: null,
  exceptionMessage: null }
```

How do I get the logs (results) of executing the above Apex code, i.e. the value returned when `UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization()` is executed?

Answer (score 1):

You would query the [ApexLog](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexlog.htm) object (tooling API), then get the log's contents via /sobjects/ApexLog/*id*/Body/. I don't know if there's a more straightforward way to get at this (sfdx force:apex:execute seems to do this all at once, but I don't know what magic is involved here).

Answer (score 0):

Below code subscribes to salesforce internal streaming channel and then apex log can be filtered based on operation type. Remember to use 36.0 as internal channels doesn't work for  version > 36.0.

```
constructor(container) {
            this.container = container
            this.conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: "{!$API.Session_Id}" });
             // Success!
            this.subscription = this.subscribe('/systemTopic/Logging',function(message) {
              console.log(message)
            },-1); // -2 is all retained events
             
             
         }
         subscribe(channel,callback,replayId){
            
            const exitCallback = () =>{console.log('exit')};
            const authFailureExt = new jsforce.StreamingExtension.AuthFailure(exitCallback);
            
            const replayExt = new jsforce.StreamingExtension.Replay(channel, replayId);
            const conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: "{!$API.Session_Id}" });
            conn.version = '36.0';
            const fayeClient = conn.streaming.createClient([
            authFailureExt,
            replayExt
            ]);
            fayeClient.disable('websocket');
            const subscription = fayeClient.subscribe(channel, callback).errback((error)=>{console.error(error)});
            
            return subscription
         }
```